# Usage of "I'm incredulous!" as an exclamation of shock or disbelief

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, word-usage

Would the exclamation "I'm incredulous!" be an appropriate response to finding out some unexpected news, if the intention is to convey shock or disbelief?

Comment: Yes, though a bit formal/stuffy/pretentious in register. (Cue my British friends here saying it's totally fine ...;)

Comment: There may be appropriate or inappropriate responses, but no correct or incorrect ones unless you're taking a school exam.

Comment: That aside, what's wrong with "I don't believe it!" or "That's unbelievable!" or "I'm shocked!" or "That is shocking!"?

Comment: @DanBron I'm a pretentious German living in England ;-)

Comment: @Robusto Thank you. I've 'corrected' my misuse of the word _correct_.

Comment: *We were incredulous that such deep divisions were apparent in a profession that should be working together.* (and more at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incredulous) What's the issue here? Of what and why exactly is the OP unsure?

Comment: Unless there's more detail, this would be a GR.

Comment: @DanBron - I'm British and it seems slightly odd usage to me. As you say, strangely formal. I think people don't tend to describe their *own* mental state in this way, in conversation. "What?", "She didn't!", "No!", "Really?" or "that's amazing!" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: "Well flip me over and paint me blue!", "You could knock me over with a feather!" are other less formal, yet quite verbose expressions. :-)

Comment: Ein gezierter Deutscher. Ich bin erstaunt.

Comment: *Incredulous* is appropriate if you are trying to say that you do not believe it.  The word has also taken on a looser meaning of just being surprised.  But if it were I, I would say *surprised* or *astonished* if I meant that, and *incredulous* if I meant that I do not believe it or I find it hard to believe.

Comment: Yes, that is totally appropriate, on the same level as "That's unbelievable!". Of course, you probably don't mean literally (I mean that literally) 'impossible to believe', but that it is difficult to believe or hyperbolic for unexpected.

Comment: I'll be the dissenting voice, then: using “I'm incredulous!” as an exclamation of shock or disbelief is extremely jarring to me. I'd label it ungrammatical and assume whoever said it was a non-native speaker. _X is incredulous_ as a stand-alone sentence (with no _of Y_ after it) is to me a statement of permanent state: _X is an incredulous person_. It sounds quite bizarre to use it for a fleeting thing like disbelief at something you've just heard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a story and you want to have someone who has just received a piece of shocking and totally unexpected information say so in a believable way, I would advise against having the character say "I'm incredulous!"—unless the character is, say, a fictionalized William F. Buckley Jr.

It's not that *incredulous* inaccurately describes the state of mind of such a character; it's that someone in that state of mind is highly unlikely to respond to a sudden shock with so considered a descriptive term. Far more likely is a simpler expression such as "I can't believe it!" or "I'm stunned!" or "You're lying!" or "Inconceivable!" or the old standby "I'm shocked, shocked!" or even something monosyllabic like "What!" or "Nooooo!" I would even expect "I'm flabbergasted!" to reach the top of a typical shocked person's mental Rolodex of suitable expressions sooner than "I'm incredulous!" would.

But every person (like every person's vocabulary) is different, and it may be that the person you have in mind would in fact exclaim "I'm incredulous!" right off the bat—just as another person might blurt out "I am experiencing a temporary, albeit disorienting, state of commingled astonishment and disapprobationary uncertainty!" Ultimately, the words that a person might actually speak on such an occasion are as unique and unpredictable as the person is.

Answer (score 0):

If ever you were to use "incredulous", that would be the perfect time.  The problem is that most people do not know the word, so you might have to explain. Since you're admittedly "pretentious", that might not bother you. Similar cautions apply to "obviate", and "comprise" which some people have heard, and some use, but almost nobody (in America, anyway) uses correctly. So they might  be incredulous when you use any of these words correctly.